# Xcode 9 - No option to create dylib project iOS

Tags: xcode

I remember in old Xcode there was option under *Create New Project* there was option to create *BSD Dynamic Library* - dylib. However now I see only *Cocoa Framework*, *Static Library* and *Metal Library*.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you mean _macOS_? Xcode never supported dylibs for iOS.

Comment: How come? iOS is using dylibs. For example /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib

Comment: Yes, dynamic libs are possible in iOS, but Apple doesn't support custom dynamic libs. They make no sense, because you can't install them on a non-rooted device.

Comment: I see, what i have in mind is jailbroken device. How can i create/adapt project for such ?

Comment: You can create a static library project and convert it either to a dynamic one or create a dynamic one with a custom build phase. Creating a dylib for iOS works almost like on macOS / Linux. But why you are using no static lib?

Comment: It's simple MobileSubstrate tweak to Cydia. How to convert static lib to dynamic lib ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may create a project for an iOS static lib, and create a dynamic lib from the static one with a custom build phase with the following command:

```
xcrun --sdk iphoneos clang -arch <ARCH> -shared -all_load \
    -o lib<NAME>.dylib lib<NAME>.a
```

where `<ARCH>` is either `armv7` or `arm64` and `<NAME>`is the base name of your lib. You may check or list the architectures with `file` command. E.g.:

```
file <path>/lib<NAME>.a`
lib<NAME>.a (for architecture armv7):   current ar archive random library
lib<NAME>.a (for architecture arm64):   current ar archive random library
```

If more than one architecture is listed, Xcode has produced a universal static library. In this case you may create a universal shared library with multiple `-arch` flags:

```
xcrun --sdk iphoneos clang -arch armv7 -arch arm64 -shared -all_load \
    -o lib<NAME>.dylib lib<NAME>.a
```

You may need to specify additional linker flags (e.g. `-l` for linking non-standard libs).

Comment: Nice! Thank you :)