# dart/flutter: How to ship iOS apps using flutter frontend vs. C/C++ backend to App Store?

Tags: ios, flutter, dynamic-linking, ffi

### Goal

I'm building an iOS app using flutter for frontend, and C/C++ as backend. They must interoperate through FFI, which is a language binding scheme through C dynamic libraries. I intend to submit it to iOS App Store.

### Problems

The [Dart FFI sample on accessing C-struct](https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/tree/master/ffi/structs) works on macOS through dynamic liking and binding. Now dynamic linking is technically possible on iOS according to [Xcode 9 - No option to create dylib project iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209855/xcode-9-no-option-to-create-dylib-project-ios), however, it's unclear to me how to ship the app to AppStore, because dynamic linking is not allowed according to [Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) Section 2.5.2.

> 2.5.2 Apps should be self-contained in their bundles, and may not read or write data outside the designated container area, **nor may they
>   download, install, or execute code which introduces or changes
>   features or functionality of the app, including other apps.**
>   Educational apps designed to teach, develop, or allow students to test
>   executable code may, in limited circumstances, download code provided
>   that such code is not used for other purposes. Such apps must make the
>   source code provided by the Application completely viewable and
>   editable by the user.

Quite a few SO questions confirm this problem, such as:

- [can I use dynamic library(shared object) in my iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187649/can-i-use-dynamic-libraryshared-object-in-my-iphone-app)
- [Will Appstore reviewers allow us to use dynamic library in iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504617/will-appstore-reviewers-allow-us-to-use-dynamic-library-in-ios8)

Then [official flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop) says

> Dynamically linked libraries are automatically loaded by the dynamic
>   linker when the app starts. Their constituent symbols can be resolved
>   using DynamicLibrary.process. You can also get a handle to the library
>   with DynamicLibrary.open to restrict the scope of symbol resolution,
>   **but it’s unclear how Apple’s review process handles this.**

### Questions

- As of the date when I post this (2020), does this say that I could never ship an app using this architecture to App Store?
- Is it possible that I static link my C/C++ code into a single binary of a flutter app? Take Unity as an example, [their iOS plugin system recompiles the plugin into native app](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html). If flutter has a similar mechanism, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers saying you can't use dynamic libraries on iOS date to before iOS 8, when support for user-provided dynamic libraries was added.

Nothing in 2.5.2 days you can't use dynamic libraires as long as they are shipped as part of your app. So:

> As of the date when I post this (2020), does this say that I could never ship an app using this architecture to App Store?

No it doesn't, as long as "this architecture" refers to using a dynamic library that you link to at build time and bundle into your application.

Answer (score 0):

Adding inputs from Reddit's FlutterDev channel

> @escamoteur
>
> As I understand it you are not allowed to load any library from
> outside your installation folder. Especially not downloading something
> at a later point of time. Could you make this a Stackoverflow question
> and tag it with Flutter?
>
> @airflow_matt
>
> Since iOS 8 there can be shared libraries in the bundle, when properly
> codesigned I don't see why dlopen wouldn't work. Or you can link the
> library with main executable itself (just like flutter does) and
> dlopen self (DynamicLibrary.process()). I think it's worth a shot.